# Voltage phase delay

Tags: ac, filter, delay, phase

Is there a method of delaying the phase of  AC voltages? I ask because if I could somehow create a second identical and overlapping sine wave **one quarter cycle** ahead of the original AC waveform in a power supply I would end up with a waveform that is much closer to DC and much easier to filter out.

Comment: I assume you mean a quarter-cycle. A half-cycle is essentially what you get with a full-wave bridge rectifier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.

As your intention is for 'easier to filter' rectified power, unfortunately none of them are a free lunch, none a trick that is less costly in energy storage than simply storing the energy when it's available, and letting it out to your load when the incoming power is low.

You could use one or more LC filters to phase shift an incoming signal, to create a synthetic three or more phase signal from a single phase input. Unfortunately the ideal sizes of Ls and Cs you need vary with the load you are applying, and will need to be adjusted as the load varies. If you are trying to improve a post-rectifier reservoir capacitor that has to store (for instance) 100J to get the output from one half cycle to the next, then your L and C filter components will need to be able to store more than that, which makes them bigger and more expensive than the DC filter you want to ease.

You could of course pay for a 3 phase supply to your premises. In the bad old days, you might buy a single phase motor driving a 3 phase generator.

These days, the 'power factor corrected switched mode power supply' does a good job at your task, even though it doesn't do it quite the way you want. It rectifies mains, without a simple post-rectifier filter capacitor. Then it uses a boost converter to charge an energy storage capacitor (which stores enough energy to see it from half cycle to half cycle) using a programmed current draw so that it looks like a resistive load to the mains side. Then it runs a converter from the energy storage cap to the output.

So, the PFC-SMPS is no free lunch, but it has a simple energy store, looks like a clean load to the mains, no nasty tuning of LC filters, no running machinery, and no workmen installing a new mains feeder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible, with a center-tapped coil (autotransformer), or a center-tapped output coil on a transformer.   The latter is a very common power supply component.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcU5T8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Half-cycle phase shift, of course, is the same as polarity inversion.

Comment: I don't want a phase shift, just a phase delay. I want to have the main sinewave and then an alternative sinewave in phase and one half cycle ahead of the original sign wave, this would fill in the ripple gaps in between the normal signwave.

Comment: Doxylover is right, I want 1 quarter cycle not half cycle.

Comment: For a quarter cycle, the power times time (energy) storage requirement is going to be a problem.   Inductors, capacitors, flywheels... SOME kind of storage of energy will be required (and often that is hard to scale, so only works with predictable loads).